# Uncertainty about the ensemble average?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, error-analysis, statistics

Does an uncertainty in momentum of $\Delta p$ mean that the actual momentum is in the range $\langle p \rangle - \Delta p\space <p< \langle p\rangle+\Delta p\space$ ? Or does it mean that the actual momentum is in the range $p_{measured} - \Delta p< p< p_{measured}+\Delta p\space$ ?

Comment: Are you familiar with [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that if you measure the momentum of many copies of the same system you will get a distribution with the mean as $\langle p\rangle$ and the second moment as $\langle p^2\rangle$. Then the uncertainty $\Delta p $ is just the standard deviation of that distribution, i.e. $\Delta p = \sigma_p = \sqrt{\langle p^2\rangle - \langle p\rangle^2}$.

Comment: Just a nitpick: the mean square momentum is the second moment, not the first (the mean is the first moment). Also \langle \rangle brackets ($\langle \rangle$) look much better than angle bracksts (<>).

Comment: But this means that possible momentums can be greater than  $\langle p\rangle + \Delta p$ and $p_{measured} + \Delta p$ , right?

Comment: Heads up, you can use \rangle for $\rangle$ and \langle for $\langle$ ;)

Comment: @Achilles'Advisor Yes, it's possible.

Comment: But, $p_{measured}$ is just a single measurement and is not necessarily equal to the mean of its distribution $\langle p\rangle$.

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote them separately.